# logback.xml throws ERROR ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:14 - no applicable action for [Properties]

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, logback, azure-application-insights

i am using logback.xml with springboot application . log back throws  no appender applicable exception for type of appenders.

**version:**
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-logback', version: '2.0.0-BETA'

**Logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/app/</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/app/a_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%class] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SPRING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/apps/log/spring_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%class] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="aiAppender" 
              class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
         </appender>
    <root level="trace" additivity="false">
                  <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />

        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: [Dhaval Doshi] I think the error you described in the title of the issue seems to be coming from ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender. Can you try to once remove the AI-Logback appender from the XML and see if issue persists. If it does then we can investigate further.